# Swedish letters wont show

Tags: sql, pdo, collation

I have a litte problem with my website with characters. If someone uses swedish characters Å,Ä or Ö  it will be replaced with air. Its not a swedish site but if someone uses it they can post blank messages even tho I use trim (php) on my post and check length

if someone for example writes a message "Nä bää ööl" it will only insert the first letter which is is N. if the sentence starts with Å,Ä or Ö and no matter waht is after it will just be blank.

My collation is utf8_general_ci , I tried changing to utf8_swedish_ci but still the same

Must be something serverside if It inserts correct when I run the query directly in phpmyadmin.

Can it be something with PDO? because before when i used mysqli i did not have this problem.

I have tried setting names to utf8 without results:

```
$db = new PDO( 
'mysql:host=blabla;dbname=secret', 
'root', 
'password', 
array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8") 
);
```

## Edit

Putting `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` in my php seem to work but weird i never had to do this before...

Comment: You should post the solution as an "answer", so it is easier for others to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by putting `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` in my PHP.